# iOS asihttp request how to log form

Tags: ios, forms, post, asihttprequest

I need to send a ASI http request, a post form,

when I check the body for my request it seems empty, 
how to check what the body is?, why is it empty?

thanks!

```
- (void)sendUnsentEntries {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    if (!sendingEntries) {

        sendingEntries = YES;
        Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];

        BOOL errorsSending = NO;
        NSInteger unsentCount = 0;

        if ([Client unsubmittedCount] > 0 && [reachability isReachable]) {            

            NSString *host = [self apiHost];

             for (Client* clientToSend in [Client allUnsubmitted]) {

                 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", host]];

                 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
                 [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
                 request.requestMethod = @"POST";

                 [request setPostValue:clientToSend.name forKey:@"name"];
                 [request setPostValue:clientToSend.territory forKey:@"territory"];

                 NSLog(@"name:: %@", clientToSend.name);

                 //LOGING THE FOR THE REQUEST
                 NSString *requ = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request postBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

                 NSLog(@"request body: %@", requ);

                 [request startSynchronous];


                 NSError *error = [request error];
                 if (!error) {
                     NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

                     NSLog(@"response :::%@",responseString);

                     if ([responseString isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
                         clientToSend.submitted = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                     }              



                 } else {
                     NSLog(@"error: %@", [error description]);
                 }

                 [[self managedObjectContext] save:nil];

        }

        unsentCount += [Client unsubmittedCount];




        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:unsentCount];

        if (errorsSending && showSendingErrors) {

        }

    }


    sendingEntries = NO;

    [pool release];
}

}
```

so I get for my 
log of:: `request body:` an empty response,

is this the way to log the body of the form?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post body isn't built until the form is submitted to the server.

You have two options:

1. Log the post body after `[request startSynchronous];`
2. call `[request buildPostBody];` before the NSLog